# how to hide an image after seconds from its appearing ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, var

**so i used this code to show my image**

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
  @IBAction func ness(_ sender: Any) {
      // when button tapped this code will execute
      imageView.isHidden = false
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       imageView.isHidden = true   
   }

}
```

**now i want the image to be invisible after seconds from its appearing
and i want to do that for multiple times, should i double the same code for the otehr image views and other buttons ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function

```
func hideImageAfterTime(time: CFTimeInterval , imageView: UIImageView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + time) {
      imageView.isHidden = true
    }
  }
```

how to use

```
@IBAction func ness(_ sender: Any) {
      // when button tapped this code will execute
       hideImageAfterTime(time: 2, imageView: imageView)
    }
```